# Jquery Ajax Calls With CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I am trying to set up a way for two tables on my page to updated automatically or if correct me if I am wrong "Asynchronously". I need second to second updates as well. I am also using CodeIgnighter MVC framework, and as for my tables I am using DataTables. My Jquery goes as follows :

```
<script>
        function updatewaiting(){
        $('.display').load('https://www.finaidtest.com/index.php/studentqueue_controller/data');
        }
        setInterval( "updatewaiting()", 1000 );

    </script>
```

My tables are as follows :

```
<table id='waiting' class='display'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>A Number</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Time Waiting</th>
            <th>Reason for visit</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Aid Year</th>
            <th>Staff Comments</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php
        $options = array("" => "", 'start' => 'Start Session', 'stop' => 'Student Not Present', 'abandon' => 'End Session',);
        foreach ($waiting as $row) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo anchor('studentqueue_controller/history/' . urlencode($row['anum']) . '', htmlspecialchars($row['anum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), 'target="_blank"'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['first'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['last'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['SECOND'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['reason'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['studentcomments'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['aidyear'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['counselorcomments'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php echo form_open('studentqueue_controller/counselorscreen/' . urlencode($row['id']) . ''); ?>
                <?php echo form_dropdown('options', $options, ""); ?>
                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<table id='beingseen' class='display'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>A Number</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Sign In Time</th>
            <th>Staff Member</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $options1 = array("" => "", 'continue' => 'Continue Session', 'terminate' => 'Terminate Session',);
        foreach ($beingseen as $row1) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['anum'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['first'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['last'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['signintime'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['fname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row1['starttime'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
                <td>
                <?php echo form_open('studentqueue_controller/counselorscreen/' . urlencode($row1['id']) . ''); ?>
                <?php echo form_dropdown('options', $options1, ""); ?>
                <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit'); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>


        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The Jquery function is calling on my data() method in my controller and all that does is query the database  :

```
function data(){
    $this->load->model('queue_model');

    $data['waiting'] = $this->queue_model->waiting();
    $data['beingseen'] = $this->queue_model->beingseen();
    }
```

I am quite confused as to why when I look into my network tab I see the ajax calls, but I do not see a response in the network tab.

Just an up date :

```
Array ( [waiting] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 176 [0] => 176 [anum] => A00163047 [1] => A00163047 [first] => rix [2] => rix [last] => aja [3] => aja [SECOND] => 62:47:39 [4] => 62:47:39 [reason] => Award Status [5] => Award Status [studentcomments] => [6] => [aidyear] => 13-14 [7] => 13-14 [counselorcomments] => [8] => ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 179 [0] => 179 [anum] => A00163047 [1] => A00163047 [first] => rix [2] => rix [last] => aja [3] => aja [SECOND] => 00:22:29 [4] => 00:22:29 [reason] => Award Status [5] => Award Status [studentcomments] => [6] => [aidyear] => 13-14 [7] => 13-14 [counselorcomments] => [8] => ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 178 [0] => 178 [anum] => A12345678 [1] => A12345678 [first] => ririri [2] => ririri [last] => ririir [3] => ririir [SECOND] => 00:24:21 [4] => 00:24:21 [reason] => Award Status [5] => Award Status [studentcomments] => [6] => [aidyear] => 13-14 [7] => 13-14 [counselorcomments] => [8] => ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 177 [0] => 177 [anum] => A99999999 [1] => A99999999 [first] => rux [2] => rux [last] => ajaj [3] => ajaj [SECOND] => 00:29:20 [4] => 00:29:20 [reason] => Award Status [5] => Award Status [studentcomments] => [6] => [aidyear] => 13-14 [7] => 13-14 [counselorcomments] => [8] => ) ) [beingseen] => )
```

My data function in fact is returning data to the controller. I just did a print_r on my data. however that array of returned data is being placed into the table itself,

Comment: Your data function isn't returning anything.

Comment: Yup, it's returning to the controller, but the controller isn't returning it back to the view. There is no return, no print, the view is never seeing that data.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should load a view and print it in javascript using `load()`, so use:

```
function data(){
        $this->load->model('queue_model');

        $data['waiting'] = $this->queue_model->waiting();
        $data['beingseen'] = $this->queue_model->beingseen();

        echo $this->load->view('myview',$data,true);
    }
```

and your view will be outputted where you are specifiying with `$(_element).load();`

just to be sure you understood the load() jquery method:

when you do `$('div#element').load('myfile.php');` you are `outputtting the returning data from myfile.php` `into the <div id="element"></div> html` element

Comment: Still noting be shown in the network tab, and also what do I do with the json_encoded data? Just throw it at the view?

Comment: Right if I do that, then tables are then continuously popping up destroying the view of the page.

Comment: @Joe remember, **load() --->is what you want to output** , **$('.display') --->is where you are going to output**  ;)

Comment: I'm sorry? I am very knew to jquery

Comment: @Joe no problems, when you do $('#element').load('myfile.php'); you are outputtting the returning data from myfile.php into the id="element" html element

Comment: Correct, so if I output the view as well as the data then the page with become distorted with multiple tables overlapping one another.

Comment: Is it possible to just retrieve the data itself not the view?

Comment: @Joe sure, you can return everything you want , just use echo;